# Insert line after every match of a specific pattern in file, using ansible or unix commands

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, ansible

I am trying to insert a line after each occurrence of a specific string in a text file. I tried with the `lineinfile` ansible module but it can only insert a line after the last or the first instance of the matched string in a file. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this using shell scripting or ansible playbook. I am using linux operating system so any unix command to solve this will help.

As shown below I am trying to insert `mba` after every line starting with `foo`:

**Original txt file contents:**

```
foo
ab
zz
foo='dummy'
cd
zz
foo='dats'
lm
xx
```

**Required output:**

```
foo
mba
ab
zz
foo='dummy'
mba
cd
zz
foo='dats'
mba
lm
xx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"**Insert 'mba' after every line starting with text 'foo'.**"*

A: Use *replace* in Ansible, e.g. given the file

```
shell> cat foo.txt
foo
ab
zz
foo='dummy'
cd
zz
foo='dats'
lm
xx
```

the task

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: foo.txt
        regexp: '^foo(.*)$'
        replace: |-
          foo\1
          mba
```

gives

```bsh
shell> cat foo.txt
foo
mba
ab
zz
foo='dummy'
mba
cd
zz
foo='dats'
mba
lm
xx
```

---

The task below gives the same result and is idempotent

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: foo.txt
        regexp: 'foo(.*)\n(?!mba)(.*)'
        replace: |-
          foo\1
          mba
          \2
```

Comment: All the answers are working for me but since this answer was the first to reply correctly, I am accepting this answer. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @deb you should always accept the answer you're going to use, not just the first answer you get.

Answer (score 4):

An `awk`-based solution might look as follows:

```
awk '{print} /^foo/{print "mba"}' input.txt
```

This will print the current line by default, but if it happens to start with `foo`, it will also print `mba` on an additional line before processing proceeds to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of choices:

- `perl`

  ```
  $ perl -pe 's/^foo.*/$&\nmg/' file
  foo
  mg
  ab
  zz
  foo='dummy'
  mg
  cd
  zz
  foo='dats'
  mg
  lm
  xx
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  $ awk '1;/^foo/{print "mg" }' file
  foo
  mg
  ab
  zz
  foo='dummy'
  mg
  cd
  zz
  foo='dats'
  mg
  lm
  xx
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`awk`

```
awk '/foo/ {$0 = $0"\nmba"}1' $file
```

`sed`

```
sed 's/foo.*/&\nmba/' $file
```

```
foo
mba
ab
zz
foo='dummy'
mba
cd
zz
foo='dats'
mba
lm
xx
```

Comment: Consider a line saying `data='foo'` or `foobar`.